# How to initialize property in local scope when using AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-style

I have a list of strings and buttons that change color property of each string in local scope. Every new added string will be black, because get color property from Controller scope. How can initialize color property in local scope of new string?

It is just a example to demonstrate my problem. So, in real project I can’t add new property to List (like currentColor: 'Red'), or something else. I just want to know: How can I set value to property in local scope when this scope creating.

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

        MyApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.color = 'Black';
            $scope.list = [
                { text: 'text1' },
                { text: 'text2' },
                { text: 'text3' }
            ]

            $scope.AddNewText = function () {
                $scope.list.push({ text: 'text' + ($scope.list.length + 1) });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <div ng-repeat="item in list">
                <span style="color:{{color}}">{{item.text}}</span>
                <button data-ng-click="color = 'Red'">Red</button>
                <button data-ng-click="color = 'Green'">Green</button>
                <button data-ng-click="color = 'Blue'">Blue</button>
                <button data-ng-click="color = 'Black'">Black</button>
            </div>
            <button data-ng-click="AddNewText()">Add new text</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Why doesn't each item have it's own color?

Comment: Question is not clear please elaborate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only change one html line that will handle the default value of color by using `ng-style` directive.

```
<span ng-style="{'color':color||'Black'}">{{item.text}}</span>
```

You html will look like below

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in list"> 
            <span ng-style="{'color':color||'Black'}">{{item.text}}</span>
            <button data-ng-click="color = 'Red'">Red</button>
            <button data-ng-click="color = 'Green'">Green</button>
            <button data-ng-click="color = 'Blue'">Blue</button>
            <button data-ng-click="color = 'Black'">Black</button>
        </div>
        <button data-ng-click="AddNewText()">Add new text</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

No need to set any color value from the controller. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/190/)

Hopefully I understand your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` creates it's own code. To initialize the local scope you can use `ng-init`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-init="color = 'red'">
     <span style="color:{{color}}">{{item.text}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make $scope.list an array of objects which contain both the text and color.

```
 $scope.list = [
                { text: 'text1',color: 'black' },
                { text: 'text2',color: 'black' },
                { text: 'text3',color: 'black' }
            ]
```

Html:

```
        <span style="color:{{item.color}}">{{item.text}}</span>
            <button data-ng-click="item.color = 'Red'">Red</button>
```

If you want initialize without list, You want to use $watch.

```
$scope.$watch('list', function() {
       $scope.color = 'black';
       console.log('list has changed, do whatever you want');
   });
```

Comment: It is very good solution. However, in real project I do not want to add any additional properties to List. So, I interested if has any way to initialize local scope properties. If there is no such ways, I will use your solution.

Comment: i added to answer solution with $watch, which listen to variable changes. It may work without two-dimensional objects.